# Document library file naming convention

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

Users uploads excel files to Share-point site every day.

Problem: Excel file names are not consistent so i came up with some file naming convention.

Is there any way we can reject a file that is ready to be uploaded if proper naming convention is not followed.

For instance: 
Good file naming convention
Filename_YYYY_MM.xls

Wrong/Bad file naming convention: This could be anything other than what’s above

Let me know if it’s possible to reject a file or user wont be able to upload because proper file naming convention is not followed.

If it's possible, Please let me know how to make it work. I'm a newbie to SP.

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes i do have Visual Studio

Comment: ok, and you would like to notify the user somehow if their name isn't conventional? Or can you just ignore it and close the upload dialog?

Comment: Yes. It would be good. If i can notify user about the name is not correct.

Comment: Any resolution on this Colbs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accomplished this with a simple Sandbox solution in SharePoint 2010.  Create an Event Receiver that will attach to a document library.

Below is the code that I used:

```
public class DocumentLibraryEventReceiver : SPItemEventReceiver
{

    const string _threeNumPrefixRegex = "^[0-9]{3}.*";
    const string _fileErrorMessage = "Non-conforming File Name:  File names must have a three-number prefix and be no more than 25 characters long.";
    const string _folderErrorMessage = "Non-conforming Folder Name: Folder names can not be longer than 25 characters.";

    private void Validate(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.Continue;

        if (properties == null) return;
        if (properties.List == null) return;

        // Don't enforce Validation rules on Site Assets
        if (properties.List.IsSiteAssetsLibrary) return;
        if (properties.List.IsApplicationList) return;
        if (properties.List.BaseType != SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary) return;
        if (((SPDocumentLibrary)properties.List).IsCatalog) return;
        if (properties.List.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.HomePageLibrary) return;
        if (properties.List.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.WebPageLibrary) return;

        string fileName = properties.AfterUrl.Substring(properties.AfterUrl.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);

        // HACK: this is kind of a crappy way of determining if the item adding is a file or a folder.
        //       In the Web client the ContentTypeId is set in the after props so we can determine if 
        //       it is a folder child. That property is not there in Explorer view (others?) and should 
        //       handle the majority of cases.  This is a "solve *most* cases" solution.
        bool isFile;

        if (null != properties.AfterProperties["vti_docstoretype"])
        {
            Int32 vtiDocStoreType = (Int32)properties.AfterProperties["vti_docstoretype"];
            isFile = (0 == vtiDocStoreType);
        }
        else if (null != properties.AfterProperties["ContentTypeId"])
        {
            SPContentTypeId contentTypeId = new SPContentTypeId(properties.AfterProperties["ContentTypeId"].ToString());
            isFile = (false == contentTypeId.IsChildOf(SPBuiltInContentTypeId.Folder));
        }
        else if (null != properties.AfterProperties["vti_filesize"])
        {
            Int32 vtiFileSize = (Int32)properties.AfterProperties["vti_filesize"];
            isFile = (vtiFileSize > 0);
        }
        else isFile = false;

        if ((fileName.Length > 25) ||
            (isFile && (false == Regex.IsMatch(fileName, _threeNumPrefixRegex))))
        {
            properties.ErrorMessage = (isFile) ? _fileErrorMessage : _folderErrorMessage;
            properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// An item is being added.
    /// </summary>
    public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        try
        {
            this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
            base.ItemAdding(properties);

            Validate(properties);
        }
        finally
        {
            this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// An item is being updated
    /// </summary>
    public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        try
        {
            this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
            base.ItemUpdating(properties);

            Validate(properties);
        }
        finally
        {
            this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```